# Concatenate a text string with today's date

Tags: sas

I am trying to construct a comment variable that combines a text string with today's date. Both of these attempts result in a comment variable with only the text string with a note in the log:
NOTE: Variable commment2 is uninitialized.

data want;
set have;
format comment2 mmddyy10. ;
comment1 = 'The date of last update is ';
comment2 = today();
comment = cats (comment1,put(commment2,mmddyy10.));
run;`

```
data want;  
set have;   
    format comment2 mmddyy10. ;     
    comment1 = 'The date of last update is ';   
    comment2 = today();     
    comment = cats (comment1,vvalue(commment2,mmddyy10.));     
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

That note means your code references a variable that doesn't exist.  The cause is a typo where you have an extra `m` in your code:

```
comment = cats (comment1,vvalue(commment2,mmddyy10.));  *commment2 has extra m;
```

Try:

```
data want;  
    format comment2 mmddyy10. ;     
    comment1 = 'The date of last update is ';   
    comment2 = today();     
    comment = catx (" ",comment1,put(comment2,mmddyy10.));     
    put comment= ;
run;
```

Comment: Boy, do I feel dumb!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll remind myself to look for typo's before assuming my code is bad.

Comment: Don't feel bad. Typos happen all the tim